# Invoke JS function with npm run build in background.js of chrome extension

Tags: javascript, npm, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to automate my workflow while developing a **chrome extension** and right now am stuck in automating the extension reload in the browser. I'm trying to run it automatically after every build.

**in background.js**

```
function extensionReload() {
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, tabs => {
    // NB: see https://github.com/xpl/crx-hotreload/issues/5

    if (tabs[0]) {
      chrome.tabs.reload(tabs[0].id);
    }

    chrome.runtime.reload();
  });
}; 
export { extensionReload }; //export as module. Not sure if necessary
```

**in package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "reload-extension":  "node background.js extensionReload",
    "build-script": "gulp background && gulp content && gulp popup && gulp manifest && gulp third-parties",
    "build": "npm run build-script && npm run build-css-chrome && npm run build-css-firefox && npm run reload-extension"
} // I have left some things out for faster read
```

but when I run it I get the following **error**:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! browser-ext@1.0.0 reload-extension: `node background.js extensionReload`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the browser-ext@1.0.0 reload-extension script.
```

I'm pretty new to the whole JS world so I'm guessing I have an implementation error that I seem to not be able to figure out.

Comment: Extension scripts have access to `chrome` API only when they run in the browser in special extension pages such as the background page that have an internal chrome-extension:// URL  but `node` can't do that. Find and use a hot reload package for extensions that monitors file changes automatically.

Comment: the extensionReload() function is taken out from the hot-reload package that monitors file changes. The problem is that it is hard to time the reload correclty since building takes different amount of times depending on how much ressources are available. Sometimes the reload gets triggered before building is completed.
I was hoping to be able to trigger the function as part of the other "npm run build" commands so it would be automatically timed correctly.

Comment: Won't work. You can tweak the reload package so it proceeds only when a special file is present in a configurable location.

Comment: OTOH I would probably just add a [hotkey](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands) to do it manually because reloading is not needed after editing some scripts like the popup script.

Comment: Thanks wOxxOm for the explanation and the ideas!
I will configure a hotkey to make it work quickly and then implement your other idea later for some practice.
Have a great day and stay safe!